# replacing multiple units of specific character with one unit in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, duplicates, hiveql

I have a dataset in which values are same except the number of semicolons in it resulting to different records.

For example if in a column one records has a;b;c and another record has a;;b;c, this is disabling the use of distinct function in my code. I want this to be treated as duplicate record for which ;; needs to be replaced with ;

How can we replace multiple ; with single ; in strings in a dataset in hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` as defined in [Hive UDFs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

The first argument is the string that needs to get changed. So you can call it on your table like :

```
with t as 
   (SELECT "a\;\;\;b\;\;c\;d" as col ) 
SELECT regexp_replace(t.col, "\;+", "\;") as col from t
```

This should give you the output

```
+-------+
|    col|
+-------+
|a;b;c;d|
+-------+
```

Comment: I used it this way - regexp_replace(study.trial_result, ";+| ;+", ";")

Comment: I had to escape `;` but `;+` already means one or more occurrences of `;`